# jQuery hover over picture with two sides

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jQuery, how do I hover over a picture and show another picture? I know about the hover() takes two parameters but I am not too clear on it. Someone please explain.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=0N97U4PwOeGV8QeLx4HQBg#q=jquery+hover+example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle for ya.
http://jsfiddle.net/qYb5m/

I think you're looking for a:

```
$('img').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).attr();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr();
    }
);
```

As you can see.  There are a few customizable options with the attr() tag.

The disappointed cat is because if you don't post a fiddle or code, it doesn't seem as if youve tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".your-img" ).hover(
    function() { // this function will be executed when the mouse pointer enters your img
        // try to show your second picture
    }, function() { // when the mouse pointer leaves your img
        // hide the second picture
    }
);
```

You can use css to style your second picture hidden as default.